# iPhone to Android NSMutableDictionary NSArray to HashMap ArrayList

Tags: java, android, objective-c, hashmap, nsmutabledictionary

My first post here :)

I have a summer job doing a bit of coding - I'm definitely not a pro, yet!

I'm converting this iPhone app to Android, it's nearly done. Just struggling converting this piece.

The array of 'participants' gets passed to a server via JSON.
This to me, in Android, looks like it would be an array of HashMaps. Is that correct?

Here is the Objective C:

```
NSMutableArray *participants = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSArray *listOfParticipants = [[game getListOfGameParticipants]allValues];

for (Player *playerObj in listOfParticipants)
{
    NSMutableDictionary *playerToAdd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    if ([playerObj.email length] == 0) {
        [playerToAdd setValue:playerObj.phoneNumber forKey:@"Id"];
    }
    else
    {
        [playerToAdd setValue:playerObj.email forKey:@"Id"];
    }

    [playerToAdd setValue:playerObj.firstName forKey:@"FirstName"];
    [playerToAdd setValue:playerObj.lastName forKey:@"LastName"];
    [playerToAdd setValue:playerObj.phoneNumber forKey:@"PhoneNumber"];

    [participants addObject:playerToAdd];

    [playerToAdd release];
}
```

The getListOfGameParticipants is:

```
- (NSDictionary*) getListOfGameParticipants
{
return participants ;
}
```

and the Android code I've attempted is:

```
ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> playersObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
            playersObject.put("Id", "test@test.net");
            playersObject.put("FirstName", "Test Firstname");
            playersObject.put("LastName", "Test Surname");
            playersObject.put("PhoneNumber", "Test Number");
            list.add(playersObject);
json.put("ParticipantIds", list);
```

Please help :)

Edit: It doesn't work. The server reports back:

```
The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''. '. See server logs for more details.
```

The data type expected is:

```
[DataMember]
public Player[] ParticipantIds { get; set; }
```

Edit: Further update:

I now have my array of hashmaps parsing to a JSON string in a good format. I need to parse that JSON string to a JSONObject and put that JSONObject in a JSONArray.

The following code doesn't work:

```
Map<String, String> playersObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
            playersObject.put("PhoneNumber", "TestNumber");
            playersObject.put("Id", "test@test.net");
            playersObject.put("FirstName", "Test Firstname");
            playersObject.put("LastName", "Test Surname");
            ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            list.add(playersObject);
            String jsonValue = org.json.simple.JSONValue.toJSONString(list);
            JSONObject hashMapObject = new JSONObject();
            hashMapObject.getString(jsonValue);
            JSONArray hashMapArray = new JSONArray(jsonValue);
            hashMapArray.put(hashMapObject);
```

It gives the error:

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for [{"LastName":"Test Surname","FirstName":"Test Firstname","Id":"test@test.net","PhoneNumber":"TestNumber"}]
```

Help!

Comment: So what is the problem? If it works it works and if it doesn't tell us what's wrong and we can figure out how to fix it. I'm an iOS developer, so I don't know if the Android code is correct, but it looks good to me.

Comment: It doesn't work. The server reports back "The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'Expecting state 'Element'.. Encountered 'Text'  with name '', namespace ''. '. See server logs for more details."

Comment: The JSON the server is expecting is:

[DataMember]
        public Player[] ParticipantIds { get; set; }

Comment: That does not look like JSON to me. Here's some sample JSON code: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that's the data type expected.

Comment: what is your json variable? I don't think the standard JSON library will convert your List/Map to JSON you will have to do that yourself.

Comment: It's just JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android code does not do the same thing as the iPhone code, but as far as the data structure goes it seems correct. Just compare the JSON generated by the two methods and you'll know what's wrong.

This is the JSON code the iPhone is generating:

```
[
    {
        "Id" : "value",
        "FirstName" : "value",
        "LastName" : "value",
        "PhoneNumber" : "value"
    },
    {
        "Id" : "value",
        "FirstName" : "value",
        "LastName" : "value",
        "PhoneNumber" : "value"
    },
    {
        "Id" : "value",
        "FirstName" : "value",
        "LastName" : "value",
        "PhoneNumber" : "value"
    }
]
```

Just make sure the Android code is generating the same thing.

**EDIT:**

The code for manually generating JSON in Java would look something like:

```
String json = "[";

for (Player player : participants) {
    json += "{";
    json += "\"Id\":\"" + (player.email.length() > 0 ? player.email : player.phoneNumber) + "\",";
    json += "\"FirstName\":\"" + player.firstName + "\",";
    json += "\"LastName\":\"" + player.lastName + "\",";
    json += "\"PhoneNumber\":\"" + player.phoneNumber + "\"";
    json += "},";
}

json = json.substring(0, json.length()-1) + "]";
```

I don't write Java code very often, but I think the above generates the same JSON as the Objective-C code you posted. It's not indented, but I don't think the server will care.

Comment: {"ParticipantIds":"[{LastName=Test Surname, 
FirstName=Test Firstname, 
PhoneNumber=Test Number, 
Id=Test@Test.net}]"}
is what is being generated at the moment

Comment: @JaboJG Then that's your problem. `json.put()` does not work like you expected.

Comment: ok, thanks. I'm going to investigate and see if GSON can do it.

Comment: @JaboJG I just took a quick look at GSON. Changing the last line to `gson.toJson(list);` may vary well do the trick, but I don't know. Try it.

Comment: I've tried both an array of gson'd hashmaps and doing gson.toJson on an array of hashmaps. Neither worked :(

Lots of: {serializeNulls:falsefactories:Factory[type=java.lang.String,adapter=com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13@4054a4b8], in the new JSON.

Will investigate further!

Comment: can you have a look at my recent edits to my post and give any suggestions you may have please?

Comment: @JaboJG Sorry, did not see your comment until just now. I'm not familiar with any Java JSON libraries, so I can't tell you how you should use them. However, it's quite simple to generate JSON manually and you don't really need a library for that. If you're having problems with the libraries I'd just do it manually.

Comment: @JaboJG Updated my answer to include code for generating the JSON manually with Java. If you haven't found a solution yet, this should do it for you.